# Auto loan Question

Tags: loans

I owe 16,000 in a car loan. If I pay 8,000 towards it will it lower the amount of months that I have to pay or will it lower the price of the payments?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure without knowing the specifics of your contract. But in most cases, the monthly payment is fixed, so paying extra will decrease the **number of months** you will need to make payments.

Also be sure to check if there is any early payment/prepayment penalty included in your contract.